# Androidx Migrate Error: cannot find symbol DaggerNetworkComponent

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android development and trying to migrate to androidx.
After migrating when I run the application on the device for testing it is giving following error:

`cannot find symbol DaggerNetworkComponent`

Dagger is not creating DaggerNetworkComponent for NetworkComponent and I don't know how to manually initiate the creation
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved.

I have updated my gradle version and then use the "Migrate to androidX" option.

After migration, clear and invalidate cache and do a clean build.

This worked for me.